# boolean function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let f = “she is out of work” and s = “she is spending more.” Write the following
statements in symbolic form:
1. Neither is she out of work nor is she spending more.

ANS : not f and not s

is this answer corret if not can i please get help

Comment: I think "symbolic form" means using the logical operators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is by [definition of **nor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR) and DeMorgan's Law.  So

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Neither is she out of work nor is she spending more} &\equiv \neg (f \lor g)\\
&\equiv (\neg f) \land (\neg g)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: thank you for your answers.